# Pycharm community edition not opening in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: pycharm

When I try to open Pycharm community edition on my windows 7 32 bit it gives the following error:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windos
>   you are running .Check your computers system information to see
>   whether you need an x86(32 bit) or x64(64 bit) version of the program
>   and then contact the software publisher.

Answer (score 1):

On the [System requirements](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) page it states:

> **System requirements**
>
> **64-bit** versions of Microsoft Windows 10, 8, 7 (SP1)

Maybe older versions of Pycharm were supported 32 bit.

Comment: 2019.1 drops 32 support due to bundled JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

use pycharm version 2017.3.1
This version supports 32-bit Windows 7